# Python requests with parameters

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests

I am new to Python and I am wondering if you could please help me resolve this issue that I am having. 
I am using Python 2.7 with requests module and everything goes fine except the data that I received is incorrect.

```
import requests

URL = 'https://www.cashbackforex.com/DesktopModules/Chart/Candles.ashx'
params = {'cp': '03/10/2017 7:30', 'int': '1', 'pair': '1', 'candles': '50', 'timezone': '12', 'candlestype': '0', 'prevTzld': '12', 'inst': '10351841'}

response = requests.get(URL, params=params)
print response.content
```

Data sample that I received from the code above is:

```
{"Data":"03/10/2017 07:06,1.059010000,1.059220000,1.058980000,1.059190000\n03/10/2017 ...
```

While it should be:

```
{"Data":"03/10/2017 07:06,1.060450000,1.060540000,1.060410000,1.060430000\n03/10/2017 ...
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Isn't that a server-side issue or maybe an issue with your request. I do not see anything wrong with the code you provided.

Comment: I have no idea, I have been modified and finding solutions multiple times but couldn't find one.

Comment: You should check your request parameters or the url link that you are using because all that `requests.get` does is return whatever is found It does not alter what it has retrieved. Also I would suggest that you verify that response that you are getting by try an other method like directly from the website or some other method then compare the two results. So you can pinpoint where the issue could come from.

Comment: @RemyJ: Here is the request URL that i got from inspecting the 'Network' of the site: https://www.cashbackforex.com/DesktopModules/Chart/Candles.ashx?cp=03%2F10%2F2017+07%3A30&int=1&pair=1&candles=50&timezone=12&candlestype=0&prevTzId=12&inst=10351841 ..... Query string parameters: cp: 03/10/2017 07:30, int: 1, pair: 1, candles: 50, timezone: 12, candlestype: 0, prevTzld: 12, inst: 10351841

Comment: I have posted answer using an alternative method. The output seems to to be in accordance with what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `request` I suggest `urllib2` as an alternative.
Here is an example. I've tried It and successfully retrieved the desired output.

```
import urllib2
import urllib

params = urllib.urlencode({"cp":"03/10/2017 07:30", "int":1, "pair":1, "candles":50,"timezone":12, "candlestype":0, "prevTzId":12, "inst":10351841}) 

target = "https://www.cashbackforex.com/DesktopModules/Chart/Candles.ashx?"

body = urllib2.urlopen(target + params)

print body.read()
```

The output

```
{"Data":"03/10/2017 07:06,1.060450000,1.060540000,1.060410000,1.060430000\n03/10/2017 07:07,1.06043
0000,1.060520000,1.060250000,1.060320000\n03/10/2017 07:08,1.060320000,1.060410000,1.060290000,1.06
0390000\n03/10/2017 07:09,1.060390000,1.060580000,1.060360000,1.060560000\n03/10/2017 07:10,1.06056
0000,1.060590000,1.060460000,1.060480000\n03/10/2017 07:11,1.060480000,1.060610000,1.060420000,1.06
0600000\n03/10/2017 07:12,1.060600000,1.060810000,1.060570000,1.060770000\n03/10/2017 07:13,1.06077
0000,1.060770000,1.060540000,1.060600000\n03/10/2017 07:14,1.060600000,1.060760000,1.060540000,1.06
0760000\n03/10/2017 07:15,1.060760000,1.060870000,1.060670000,1.060770000\n03/10/2017 07:16,1.06077
0000,1.060800000,1.060480000,1.060620000\n03/10/2017 07:17,1.060620000,1.060730000,1.060500000,1.06
0720000\n03/10/2017 07:18,1.060720000,1.060760000,1.060670000,1.060700000\n03/10/2017 07:19,1.06070
0000,1.060710000,1.060510000,1.060700000\n03/10/2017 07:20,1.060700000,1.060760000,1.060510000,1.06
0520000\n03/10/2017 07:21,1.060520000,1.060720000,1.060410000,1.060710000\n03/10/2017 07:22,1.06071
0000,1.060740000,1.060600000,1.060610000\n03/10/2017 07:23,1.060610000,1.060640000,1.060270000,1.06
0370000\n03/10/2017 07:24,1.060370000,1.060760000,1.060310000,1.060660000\n03/10/2017 07:25,1.06066
0000,1.060660000,1.060440000,1.060510000\n03/10/2017 07:26,1.060510000,1.060650000,1.060340000,1.06
0620000\n03/10/2017 07:27,1.060620000,1.060860000,1.060560000,1.060600000\n03/10/2017 07:28,1.06060
0000,1.060760000,1.060530000,1.060540000\n03/10/2017 07:29,1.060540000,1.061300000,1.060260000,1.06
0780000\n03/10/2017 07:30,1.060780000,1.062440000,1.060210000,1.061600000\n03/10/2017 07:31,1.06160
0000,1.062830000,1.061280000,1.062820000\n03/10/2017 07:32,1.062820000,1.063160000,1.062700000,1.06
3090000\n03/10/2017 07:33,1.063090000,1.063610000,1.063060000,1.063110000\n03/10/2017 07:34,1.06311
0000,1.063190000,1.061810000,1.061890000\n03/10/2017 07:35,1.061890000,1.062350000,1.061800000,1.06
2230000\n03/10/2017 07:36,1.062230000,1.062320000,1.061410000,1.061460000\n03/10/2017 07:37,1.06146
0000,1.062150000,1.061240000,1.061800000\n03/10/2017 07:38,1.061800000,1.062600000,1.061710000,1.06
2460000\n03/10/2017 07:39,1.062460000,1.063190000,1.061910000,1.063190000\n03/10/2017 07:40,1.06319
0000,1.063210000,1.062770000,1.063000000\n03/10/2017 07:41,1.063000000,1.063260000,1.062710000,1.06
2980000\n03/10/2017 07:42,1.062980000,1.063520000,1.062770000,1.063430000\n03/10/2017 07:43,1.06343
0000,1.063770000,1.063400000,1.063590000\n03/10/2017 07:44,1.063590000,1.063720000,1.063340000,1.06
3390000\n03/10/2017 07:45,1.063390000,1.063450000,1.063060000,1.063170000\n03/10/2017 07:46,1.06317
0000,1.064670000,1.063140000,1.064450000\n03/10/2017 07:47,1.064450000,1.064490000,1.064000000,1.06
4140000\n03/10/2017 07:48,1.064140000,1.064140000,1.063840000,1.064030000\n03/10/2017 07:49,1.06403
0000,1.064180000,1.063770000,1.063800000\n03/10/2017 07:50,1.063800000,1.063830000,1.063310000,1.06
3380000\n03/10/2017 07:51,1.063380000,1.063720000,1.063300000,1.063660000\n03/10/2017 07:52,1.06366
0000,1.063920000,1.063590000,1.063780000\n03/10/2017 07:53,1.063780000,1.063790000,1.063320000,1.06
3370000\n03/10/2017 07:54,1.063370000,1.063650000,1.063320000,1.063540000\n03/10/2017 07:55,1.06354
0000,1.063800000,1.063330000,1.063750000\n","CentralPoint":"03/10/2017 07:30","InstanceName":"US Ch
ange in NonFarm Payrolls","PeriodStart":"03/10/2017 07:06","PeriodEnd":"03/10/2017 07:55","ReportDa
te":"04/07/2017 06:30"}
```

Comment: This is my last resort solution since it does not provide me with flexibility in changing the parameters. EX: if I want to change the date and candles count, I have to go through the link carefully instead of changing it from the params.

Comment: You can use `urllib.urlencode` in order to add the arguments in the link. I've updated my answer where the arguments are in are distinct variable `params`.

Comment: Hey @RemyJ, Thanks a lot for your solutions. I have finally found an answer with using requests module in python. Apparently, I didn't know that ' and " matters in Python (I thought they are the same). Ultimately, I just change the URL from 'https://......' to "https://......." and it works just fine.

Comment: You are welcome. I'm happy that I could be of some minor help. I'm also happy that you found a correction the initial problem. And thanks for sharing your solution with me I would have not guest that the issue was related to the quotation marks. Best of lucks for what you are working on, Cheers.